# user.identity.isauthenticated is always false on api controllers

Tags: .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

In my dotnet core 2.1 razor project folder there is a folder containing my API controllers.

- The calls to the api controller keep failing at the point where i try to get the current signed in user. The curUser is returned as null

​

​

```
private  Task<AccountDetail> GetCurrentUserAsync() =>  _UserManager.GetUserAsync(HttpContext.User);

[Route("GetProjectTweets/{id}")]
[HttpGet("GetProjectTweets/{id}")]
public async Task<List<InsytModels.Tweet>> GetProjectTweetsAsync(int id)
{
    var curUser = await GetCurrentUserAsync();
    var Project = await new Project().GetAsync(_context, id, curUser.Id);

...
```

​

- Here is my startup code

​

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using INSYT.Areas.Identity.Services;
using INSYT.Hubs;
using InsytModels;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.HttpsPolicy;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UI.Services;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

namespace INSYT
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }
        readonly string MyAllowSpecificOrigins = "_myAllowSpecificOrigins";


        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls | SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;

            services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>
            {
                // This lambda determines whether user consent for non-essential cookies is needed for a given request.
                options.CheckConsentNeeded = context => true;
                options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.None;

            });
            services.Configure<ForwardedHeadersOptions>(options =>
            {
                options.ForwardLimit = 2;
                options.KnownProxies.Add(IPAddress.Parse("127.0.10.1"));
                options.ForwardedForHeaderName = "X-Forwarded-For-My-Custom-Header-Name";
            });
            services.AddHttpsRedirection(options =>
            {
                options.RedirectStatusCode = StatusCodes.Status308PermanentRedirect;
                options.HttpsPort = 443;
            });

            services.AddCors(options =>
            {
                options.AddPolicy(MyAllowSpecificOrigins,
                builder =>
                {
                    builder.AllowAnyOrigin();
                    builder.AllowAnyHeader();
                    builder.AllowAnyMethod();

                    //builder.WithOrigins("https://***.com",
                    //                    "https://www.***.com");
                });
            });

            services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1);



            services.AddDbContext<InsytDBContext>
                (options => options.UseSqlServer(connection, b => b.MigrationsAssembly("***")));

            services.AddIdentity<AccountDetail, IdentityRole>(config =>
            {
                config.SignIn.RequireConfirmedEmail = false;
            })
                .AddEntityFrameworkStores<InsytDBContext>()
                .AddDefaultTokenProviders();

            services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(options =>
            {
                // Cookie settings
                options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
                options.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(15);

                options.LoginPath = "/Identity/Account/Login";
                options.SlidingExpiration = true;
            });

            services.AddSession(s => s.IdleTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30));

            services.Configure<IdentityOptions>(options =>
            {

                // Password settings.
                options.Password.RequireDigit = false;
                options.Password.RequireLowercase = true;
                options.Password.RequireNonAlphanumeric = false;
                options.Password.RequireUppercase = false;
                options.Password.RequiredLength = 6;
                options.Password.RequiredUniqueChars = 0;

                // Lockout settings.
                options.Lockout.DefaultLockoutTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5);
                options.Lockout.MaxFailedAccessAttempts = 7;
                options.Lockout.AllowedForNewUsers = true;

                // User settings.
                //options.User.AllowedUserNameCharacters =
                //"abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789-._@+";
                options.User.RequireUniqueEmail = true;
            });

            //services.AddDefaultIdentity<IdentityUser>(config =>
            //{
            //    config.SignIn.RequireConfirmedEmail = true;
            //});




            services.AddSingleton<IEmailSender, EmailSender>();
            services.Configure<AuthMessageSenderOptions>(Configuration);
            services.AddSignalR();
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
        {





            //if (env.IsDevelopment())
            //{
            //    app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            //}
            //else
            //{
            //    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
            //    app.UseHsts();
            //}
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
           app.UseHsts();

            app.UseCors(MyAllowSpecificOrigins);
            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseStaticFiles();
            app.UseCookiePolicy();

            app.UseSession();
            app.UseSignalR(routes =>
            {
                routes.MapHub<TweetHub>("/tweetHub");
            });

            app.UseAuthentication();
            app.UseMvc();
        }
    }
}
```

​

- The exact same code works in any other razor pages
- If i decorate the controller with an authorize attribute, i get a 404 not found error
- My Web app is hosted on AWS Elastic beanstalk

​

Answer (score 0):

I updated the services code

```
  services.AddCors(options =>
            {
                options.AddPolicy(MyAllowSpecificOrigins,
                builder =>
                {
                    builder.AllowAnyOrigin();
                    builder.AllowAnyHeader();
                    builder.AllowAnyMethod();
                    builder.AllowCredentials();
                });
            });
```

Then added this to my ajax query

```
  xhrFields: {
                withCredentials: true
            }
```